# React hiding components without react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 components. The app component which has everything, a menu component which has two link options: General and reviews, and the two components I’m trying to hide/show: General component and reviews component.

How can I make it so that the menu component originally shows the General component and if I click on the reviews link, it would hide the General component and show the reviews components. Then if you click on the General component link, it would hide the reviews component and show the General component. I don’t need to use router since I’m not changing links, I just need to hide and show components.

I have the idea of adding an active state on the app state but not sure how it would work.

Comment: Just google "react conditional render"

Answer (score 0):

In your App component, have a state item `currentView`, which would hold the page you would like to display, Either by using an if and else, or just hiding them when they are not the option selected

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            currentView: 'general' // general|reviews|etc...
        }
        this.changeView = this.changeView.bind(this);
    }

    changeView(viewName) {
        this.setState({
            currentView: viewName
        });
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menu">
                {this.state.currentView !== 'general' && (
                    <a onClick={() => this.changeView('general')}>
                        General
                    </a>
                )}
                {this.state.currentView !== 'reviews' && (
                    <a onClick={() => this.changeView('reviews')}>
                        Reviews
                    </a>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would the review or General component go in this code? I can understand that clicking on the links changes the link’s state but so I just do the same thing for rendering the components?